# homebrew formula not found error for a removed package

Tags: macos, homebrew

I get this message every time I open a terminal in mac

```
Error: No available formula for php55 
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap josegonzalez/php
```

php is not installed on my system and when I try cleanup or uninstall it get the error

```
Anadis-MacBook-Pro:vagrant-vms anadi$ brew rm php55
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php55
Anadis-MacBook-Pro:vagrant-vms anadi$ brew cleanup php55
Error: No available formula for php55 
Anadis-MacBook-Pro:vagrant-vms anadi$ brew cleanup php
Error: No available formula for php
```

not sure where it's coming from; how to get rid of this error?

***Update:***

brew doctor output

```
Anadis-MacBook-Pro:github anadi$ brew doctor
Warning: Your XQuartz (2.7.5) is outdated
Please install XQuartz 2.7.6:
  https://xquartz.macosforge.org

Warning: Your Homebrew is outdated.
You haven't updated for at least 24 hours, this is a long time in brewland!
To update Homebrew, run `brew update`.

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i32.2.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i64.2.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libqmi_api.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i32.la
    /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i64.la

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/osxfuse.pc

Warning: Your Homebrew is outdated.
You haven't updated for at least 24 hours, this is a long time in brewland!
To update Homebrew, run `brew update`.
Anadis-MacBook-Pro:github anadi$
```

Comment: What does `brew doctor` says?

Comment: added output, nothing about the php55 formula.

Comment: Well, there *is* no package available for php55 with brew. What does your various .profile/.bash_profile/.bash_rc contains? Is there something in there that somehow tries to run `brew install php55`?

Comment: yes there was an `export` statement pointing to that formula in `.bash_profile` removing it fixed the problem